# Spring Boot: post and process multipart/form-data request with multiple body parts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, post, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I have the following endpoint that processes the multipart/form-data requests:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Response> handleRequest(
            @RequestPart(value = "image") MultipartFile image,
            @RequestPart(value = "data") Request request, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    }
```

When I test it with IDEA rest client the endpoint is being reached as expected:

```
POST http://myUrl/test
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=xxxx
Authorization: Basic username pass

--xxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg

< C:\pathToImage\image.jpg
--xxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"
Content-Type: application/json

{
"firstName":"John",
"lastName":"Doe"
}
--xxxx
```

But when I am trying to reach this endpoint via Spring RestTemplate, I observe the 400 response and the  following error:
`Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'image' is not present]`.

The code I am using for posting the request is the following:

```
public Response test(final byte[] image, MediaType imageMimeType, final Request request) {
        String url = "http://myUrl/test";
        HttpHeaders headers = HeaderUtils.headerBasicAuth("username", "pass");
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("image", new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(image)));
        map.add("data", request.toJson());
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
        ResponseEntity<Response> result = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Response.class);
        return result.getBody();
    }
```

The approximate code of the Request class is below:

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Getter
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public final class VerifyRequest implements Cloneable, Serializable {
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    public JSONObject toJson() {
        String json;
        try {
            json = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException var3) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(var3);
        }

        return new JSONObject(json);
    }
    ....
}
```

Any suggestions how could I post such kind of request?

Comment: what does request.toJson() do ? Could you post your Request?

Comment: The problem is not in the Request object but in recognizing the image content. Nevertheless, the Request class approximate code is above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because your are not using a valid object in the *MultiValueMap* for the image field. Normally you would use *FileSystemResource* to load the image from the disk, there are many examples of that.

However if you still want to get it from a byte array you could use a *ByteArrayResource* overriding getFilename() which is necessary on the controller side. So instead of:

`map.add("image", new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(image)));`

just put:

```
ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(image) {
    @Override
    public String getFilename() {
        return "image.jpg";
    }
};
map.add("image", byteArrayResource);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter which type of `Resource` it is, as long as it is an `InputStreamSource`. So either one will work.

Comment: I just tried myself and I can not get it working with the InputStreamResource like in the question. I keep getting `MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'image' is not present`. 
However if I override getFIlename as I suggested it works. Please show any alternative using InputStreamResource

Comment: Overriding the getFileName() method helps. Thanks @pepevalbe.
I have also tried removing the filename from the request in the rest client and got 400 as well.

Comment: A filename is, indeed, required else it isn't a valid multipart argument for a file. But the underlying httpmessageconverter works equally well with each `InputStreamSource` for writing the content, however a filename is indeed required.